# Import a Vue project to Vue UI

Tags: user-interface, vue.js

I can create a new project with View UI

Is there a way to import an already existing project to Vue UI (not started with Vue UI)?

If yes, how?
Is there a version limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run up the Vue cli ui

```
$vue ui
```

Navigate via the 'more...' menu (bottom left) to Vue Project Manager (or here http://localhost:8000/project/select). You have the option to import a project.

You will however be missing some plugins if the project was not created using Vue CLI.

Mainly

```
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^3.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
  // ...
}
```

See here for more details - https://auth0.com/blog/vue-cli-ui-for-easy-project-management/